# How to check type of "typeof" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to check the type of `typeof` in JavaScript. To check it pragmatically when I tried following approaches, it gave `SyntaxError`

**Example 1:**

```
typeof typeof // SyntaxError
```

**Example 2**

```
function checkType(x) {
    return typeof x;
};
checkType(typeof); // SyntaxError
```

**So, I have two questions here:**

1. What is the type of `typeof` in JavaScript?
2. Can we write a function to retrieve it's type?

---

**Edit (to explain the purpose/curiosity behind this question):**

I am just curious if we can see the implementation of such operators (like `typeof`) in our code (or in dev console). For example, the way I can see/print the function definition of built-in functions, I just wanted to know if there could be any way to dig more and get info about such operators like `typeof`. When look at their use, to me such operators look similar to built-in functions, which takes an input and returns an output.

Comment: `typeof` is an operator. it has no value.

Comment: `typeof if` would make just as much sense: none.

Comment: typeof has no value it is an operator, it's like writing `typeof var`

Comment: The question says that _What will “typeof typeof” return in JavaScript?_, so it looks like you know the answer to it which is a `SyntaxError` unfortunately. Also  2. _Can we write a function to retrieve it's type?_ If you cannot retrieve `typeof typeof` then will writing a function, makes any difference? Also, it looks like you've already made a function to retrieve its value, then what's the problem?

Comment: @window.document Thanks. I've edited the title to be more specific.

Comment: @MaheerAli It's not sure that if the question is asking a solution to a problem, or asking a solution to a problem **which is already solved by the op** or solving their own problem and noticing that something else exists and asking the community about the behavior of a current programming language in the context. Which cannot be fixed as it is how the language behaves. If op wants to know about the typeof operator then they can refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @window.document I was just curious if we can see the implementation of such operators (like `typeof`) in our code (or in dev console). For example, the way I can see the function definition of built-in functions, I just wanted to know if there could be any to dig more and get info about such operators like `typeof`. To me such operators look similar to built-in functions, which takes an input and returns an output.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the type of typeof in JavaScript?

It isn't a value, so it doesn't have a type. `typeof` is an operator.

> Can we write a function to retrieve it's type?

No.